# TicketGrantingTicketImpl Exception - CAS 7.0.2

Tags: cas

I used the delegation identity provider with github, it run ok, and authorized my account in cas success.

```
2024-03-26 15:05:02,752 ERROR 
[org.apereo.cas.util.serialization.AbstractJacksonBackedStringSerializer] - <Cannot read/parse [{"@class":"org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl","@id":1,"id":"TGT-1-********qFm6SjQ17y...] to deserialize into type [class org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl]. This may be caused in the absence of a configuration/support module that knows how to interpret the fragment, specially if the fragment describes a CAS registered service definition. Internal parsing error is [Cannot construct instance of `org.pac4j.oauth.credentials.OAuth20Credentials` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 2090] (through reference chain: org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl["authentication"]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthentication["credentials"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.ClientCredential["credentials"])]>
2024-03-26 15:05:02,758 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - <INVALID_TICKET
 DefaultTicketStringSerializationManager.java:deserializeTicket:60
 DefaultTicketStringSerializationManager.java:lambda$deserializeTicket$1:49
 Unchecked.java:lambda$supplier$38:1695
>
2024-03-26 15:05:52,249 INFO [org.apereo.cas.services.mgmt.AbstractServicesManager] - <Loaded [2] service(s) from [EmbeddedResourceBasedServiceRegistry].>
2024-03-26 15:06:35,242 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.util.serialization.AbstractJacksonBackedStringSerializer] - <Cannot read/parse [{"@class":"org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl","@id":1,"id":"TGT-1-********qFm6SjQ17y...] to deserialize into type [class org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl]. This may be caused in the absence of a configuration/support module that knows how to interpret the fragment, specially if the fragment describes a CAS registered service definition. Internal parsing error is [Cannot construct instance of `org.pac4j.oauth.credentials.OAuth20Credentials` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 2090] (through reference chain: org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl["authentication"]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthentication["credentials"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.ClientCredential["credentials"])]>
2024-03-26 15:06:35,342 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.util.serialization.AbstractJacksonBackedStringSerializer] - <Cannot read/parse [{"@class":"org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl","@id":1,"id":"TGT-1-********qFm6SjQ17y...] to deserialize into type [class org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl]. This may be caused in the absence of a configuration/support module that knows how to interpret the fragment, specially if the fragment describes a CAS registered service definition. Internal parsing error is [Cannot construct instance of `org.pac4j.oauth.credentials.OAuth20Credentials` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 2090] (through reference chain: org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl["authentication"]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthentication["credentials"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.ClientCredential["credentials"])]>
2024-03-26 15:06:35,353 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.util.serialization.AbstractJacksonBackedStringSerializer] - <Cannot read/parse [{"@class":"org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl","@id":1,"id":"TGT-1-********qFm6SjQ17y...] to deserialize into type [class org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl]. This may be caused in the absence of a configuration/support module that knows how to interpret the fragment, specially if the fragment describes a CAS registered service definition. Internal parsing error is [Cannot construct instance of `org.pac4j.oauth.credentials.OAuth20Credentials` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 2090] (through reference chain: org.apereo.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicketImpl["authentication"]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthentication["credentials"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.ClientCredential["credentials"])]>
2024-03-26 15:06:52,256 INFO [org.apereo.cas.services.mgmt.AbstractServicesManager] - <Loaded [2] service(s) from [EmbeddedResourceBasedServiceRegistry].>
```

But the console log occured a problem as below(tikets registry into redis)

org.pac4j.oauth.credentials.OAuth20Credentials is a class file under org.pac4j.pac4j-oauth:6.0.0 pom, no parameterless constructor is provided by default, the current logic is fine under cas version 6.6.0

```
cas.authn.pac4j.github.id=xxx
cas.authn.pac4j.github.secret=xxx
cas.authn.pac4j.github.client-name=github
cas.authn.pac4j.github.callback-url=https://xxx.goho.co
```

How to fix it

Comment: Isn't this the same question you've deleted within the last hours? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78223957/ticketgrantingticketimpl-exception-cas-7-0-2

Comment: system closed，so，deleted

Comment: Yes, it was closed due to proper reasons. Did you work on any of them? Is this even related to programming? Then please share the code involved. If not, move your question to a site where this is more on-topic, like serverfault.com